# Get precision of GaussianNaive bayes

Tags: python, python-3.x, scikit-learn, precision, precision-recall

I wrote this example of https://scikit-learn.org/. but i cant find the precision??

```
import numpy as np
x = np.array([[-1, -1], [-2, -1], [-3, -2], [1, 1],[2, 1], [3, 2]])
y = np.array([1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2])
from sklearn.naive_bayes import GaussianNB
clf = GaussianNB()
clf.fit(x, y)
pred = clf.predict([[-0.8, -1]])

from sklearn.metrics import accuracy_score
accuracy_score(y,pred)
```

Answer (score 0):

You are passing as inputs for `accuracy_score()` two variables with inconsistent numbers of samples (`y` has 6 samples, `pred` has 1).

To get the precision you should pass to `sklearn.metrics.precision_score()`:

- a vector `y_true` representing ground truth (correct) target values and
- a vector `y_pred` representing estimated targets as returned by a classifier.

In your case, you do not have `y_true` about vector `[-0.8, -1]`.

See the [docs](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.precision_score.html) and the example therein.